# Using ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest a bad idea?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my app there are settings for changing how the live tile should look like (color, background and so on). Problem is that if the user changes this it takes about 30 minutes before the live tile is updated with the new settings since all the code (quite a lot of code) is beeing executed in my OnInvoke function.

Is it a bad idea to call ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest everytime the user changes the live tile settings in my app?

```
ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest("PA77RT", TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000));
```

I know that it might be considered "not perfect" doing like this but my question is if this will have any other downsides that I don't know of?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't call `ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest` outside your test-environment in a debug build.

I always encapsulate it with

```
#if DEBUG
   ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest
#endif
```

For your problem, you should simply remove the tile, and add it again, if you wish the content to update instantly. Otherwise, your users simply need to be patient.

P.S. Don't bother with the delay parameter. It'll automatically delay the launch a few seconds, due to the mechanism of the scheduled actions.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. So I need to somehow make the code available to my main app or simply duplicate the code.

Comment: Pretty much, yes. Have a shared assembly with just the code you need for those parts.